# Binding multiple select values in a dropdownlist to a string using Select2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jquery-select2

I'm using the JQuery Select2 plugin from http://select2.github.io/select2/ and am having a problem binding a model to multiple items.

I know that when using Select2 for multiple items, you can create a separate entity to hold the stored items, but in my case I'd like to use a comma delimited list.

My view code is here:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Quote.TypeofRoof,
    Model.RoofTypes,
    "", new { @class = "ddl", @multiple = "multiple", @style = "width:100%;height:35px" })
</div>
```

TypeofRoof is a string in my Quote class:

```
public string TypeofRoof { get; set; }
```

My problem is that when I submit my form with multiple items selected, only the first is saved:

[image]

[image]

What I'm after is to have the model comma separate the values, i.e.:

"Metal, Terracotta"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ListBoxFor` instead of `DropDownListFor`. Make you field array type:

```
public string[] TypeofRoof { get; set; }
```

And then on View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    x => x.Quote.TypeofRoof,
    Model.RoofTypes,
    new { @class = "ddl", multiple = "multiple", @style = "width:100%;height:35px" })
```

Comment: The only problem with having TypeofRoof as a string[] is that I can't map it directly to an EntityFramework type?

Comment: actually it's poor practice map to your DB Layer (EF in your case) right from your `View`. Better use mapping `ViewMode`l to EF Model in your `Controller`.

Comment: I'm getting an error with the ListBoxFor syntax, not sure what the problem is, but it's not syntaxed properly

Comment: Just FYI, Rooftypes is of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>